# What parts of Ember is needed when only implenting an isolated functionality?

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking to replicate the exact functionality seen here:  http://verbalink.com/services/transcription-services#transcription_rates

There's no change of URLs and no requests to the server.

What parts of the Ember framework would be needed to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember, Handlebars, and JQuery (Ember has a dependency on it).